# PHP redirects without looping

Tags: php, apache, mod-rewrite, redirect

I have two domains, domain.com and main.com. I need to go to main.com and return to domain.com

How to do these redirects without looping? And I can`t add GET parameter.

**domain.com** → **main.com** → **domain.com**

Comment: I don't think I'm stupid but I simply can't grasp this question.

Comment: What’s the purpose of the redirect anyway?

Comment: check out something and come back

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found no other solution except this:

**domain.com**

```
<?php
if(!isset($_COOKIE['flag']))
{
  setcookie('flag', 1, time() + 100, "/");
  header('location: http://main.com');
}
else
{
  setcookie('flag', '', time() , "/");
  echo 'done!';
}
?>
```

**main.com**

```
<?php
header('location: http://domain.com');
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Check the referrer.

Comment: and i understand that i can`t set referrer in headers too:(

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `header` function from the page you want to redirect to some other location:

```
header('LOCATION: url/page here');exit;
```

Answer (score 0):

<strike>**domain.com/get** - in this point you can add some additional variable then if you get into **domain.com** check this variable, if this varaible exists on `GET` then don't get into **main.com/send**</strike>

If you are using `header()` to change location, you can add in url some get variable like for example `index.php?x`. Then you can check `isset($_GET['x'])` for obtain existence of this.

**You can't do this in this form.**

Comment: Haha, why don't you just delete this answer ;)